# udisksctl command (udisks package) does not work on NixOS after upgrade to 22.11

Tags: nixos, udisks

What I get when trying to mount an external drive:

```
$ udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/sdb1

The program 'udisksctl' is not in your PATH. You can make it available in an
ephemeral shell by typing:
  nix-shell -p udisks
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Jan Tojnar pointed out on the NixOS Discourse](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/udiskie-no-longer-runs/23768/3?u=toraritte), the [NixOS 22.11 release notes](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/release-notes.html#sec-release-22.11) provide the answer:

> The `udisks2` service, available at `services.udisks2.enable`, is now disabled by default. It will automatically be enabled through services and desktop environments as needed. This also means that `polkit` will now actually be disabled by default. The default for `security.polkit.enable` was already flipped in the previous release, but `udisks2` being enabled by default re-enabled it.

So the solution is to enable `udisks2` in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`. For example, simply by adding the line:

```
# /etc/nixos/configuration.nix
services.udisks2.enable = true;
```

and rebuilding the NixOS config:

```
$ sudo nixos-rebuild switch
```